# Spring JavaConfig for java.util.Properties field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inject

Can you please tell me how to use Spring Javaconfig to directly load/autowire a properties file to a java.util.Properties field?

Thanks!

**Later edit - still searching for the answer:**
Is it possible to load with Spring JavaConfig a properties file directly into a java.util.Properties field?

Answer (score 13):

The XML base Way:

in spring config:

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" location="classpath:com/foo/my-production.properties"/>
```

in your class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myProperties")
private Properties myProperties;
```

**JavaConfig Only**

It looks like there is an annotation:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:com/foo/my-production.properties")
```

Annotating a class with this will load the properties from the file in to the Environment. You then have to autowire the Environment into the class to get the properties.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:com/foo/my-production.properties")
public class AppConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public void someMethod() {
    String prop = env.getProperty("my.prop.name");
    ...
}
```

I do not see a way to directly inject them into the Java.util.properties.  But you could create a class that uses this annotation that acts as a wrapper, and builds the properties that way.

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in how to get this result by using only Spring JavaConfig, without the xml file...

Comment: @Roxana oops.  Edited my post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a special situation where I definetely need a Properties field. I will keep in mind your idea with the wrapper, but I wonder if there isn't a simpler solution...:)

Comment: @Roxana check my answer below

Answer (score 6):

declare a `PropertiesFactoryBean`.

```
@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean mailProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("mail.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

Legacy code had following config

```
<bean id="mailConfiguration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:mail.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Converting that to Java config is super easy as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

It is an old subject but there are also a more basic solution.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public Properties myPropertyBean() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(...);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also this approach for injecting properties directly using xml configurations. The context xml has this

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:META-INF/spring/conf/myProps.properties"/>
```

and the java class just uses

```
@javax.annotation.Resource
private Properties myProps;
```

Voila!! it loads. 
Spring uses the 'id' attribute in xml to bind to the name of variable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@Configuration  
public class PropertyConfig { 

 @Bean("mailProperties")  
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")   
  public Properties getProperties() {
     return new Properties();  
  }

}
```

Make sure to define properties in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

**application.yml**:

```
root-something:
    my-properties:
        key1: val1
        key2: val2
```

Your type-safe pojo:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root-something")
public class RootSomethingPojo {

    private Properties myProperties;
```

Your container configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ RootSomethingPojo .class })
public class MySpringConfiguration {
```

This will inject the key-value pairs directly into the `myProperties` field.