# Spring Boot load properties as java.util.Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

In Spring Boot it is pretty straightforward to read properties from the application.properties (@Value), but what I would like to do is to load all properties in a `java.util.Properties` object.

Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114357/6656759 ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I want to access/load SpringBoot application.properties (not another property file).
For example if the user changes profile (i.e. dev) I would want to load the application-dev.properties without managing this logic myself but accessing the same file loaded by SpringBoot

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible. 
You can see how it can be done from [here(Click).](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) . And Before doing it, please consider:

1. Where to put property file?(Same directory as Springboot property file exists?)
2. For what purpose do you  need to use "Property" over "@Value"?
3. Will other people can read easily with code used "Property"?

Please consider to use ["Spring cloud conf"](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) if this seems to be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I am actually trying to put into java.util.Properties the content of SpringBoot application.properties, not another property file.